# How Can I Use arrayRemove Dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to make a function that will delete a note in a to-do style app. My function below works when hardcoded:

```
const deleteLabel = async (id) => {
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid), {
      labels: arrayRemove({
        cards: [
          {
            name: "mlb reg season",
            tags: "mlb, sport, sports",
          },
        ],
        id: "mlb",
      }),
    });
    // console.log("label deleted!");
  };
```

But I'm trying to format it so that it will take in an "id" as a parameter and delete the corresponding array (which is being sourced in state) in firebase/firestore like so:

```
  const deleteLabel = async (id) => {
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid), {
      label: arrayRemove({
        cards: labels[id],
      }),
    });
    // console.log("label deleted!");
  };
```

This is the entire state of labels:

[image]

And this is labels.id[0] (the parameter being passed in would be the [0] on the click handler:

[image]
Shouldn't label.id be formatted exactly as my hardcoded example above would have been?

Here is an error I keep getting making me think I cannot dynamically? I've also tried this:

> App.js:99 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Function arrayRemove() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in document users/QjB6

This is one other option I tried:

```
 const deleteLabel = async (id) => {
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid), {
      label: arrayRemove({
        id: id,
      }),
    });
    // console.log("label deleted!");
  };
```

Which doesn't work either.

Here is the component where the label/delete button
is being clicked:

```
return (
    <div className="labels">
      <div className="labels__section">
        {labelNames.map((label, i) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={i}
              onClick={() => clickHandler(i)}
              className={`${
                activeLabels === i && "labels__container--highlight"
              } labels__container`}
            >
              <h2 className="labels__label">{label}</h2>
              <img
                onClick={() => {
                  deleteLabel(i);
                  // findLabelToDelete(i);
                }}
                className="labels__delete"
                src={deleteIcon}
                alt="delete icon"
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

Lastly, here is a picture of the firestore data:
[image]

Comment: All the code snippets look correct individually. Also we cannot where you've logged those values present in the screenshots. Please share the complete component along with all the functions in a single code snippet so it's easier for us to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you Dhamaraj. I have added the component to the question. I did remove some functions that weren't related so hopefully there's enough info there to provide some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I was trying to delete JUST the ID being passed when I should have been filtering the state of labels with the id attached like so:

```
  const deleteLabel = async (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    console.log("All data", labels);
    console.log(
      "The specific label that should get deleted: ",
      labels.labels[id]
    );
    await updateDoc(doc(db, "users", currentUser.uid), {
      labels: arrayRemove(labels.labels[id]),
    });
    console.log("label deleted!");
  };
```